# Mongodb field name as numbers - how to use it in updates?

Tags: mongodb

Because of a weird bug in my code, I have a collection with field names which are stricly numbers (ex: 34344,54675,34356).
Now I try to move these fields values to another fields (ex: name,email,etc) but when I run the update command:

```
db.collection.find({"id_field" : 1996}).forEach(function (elem) {db.collection.update({_id: elem._id},{$set: {name: elem.36536}});});
```

All I get is an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

How should I handle it? I already tried with elem[36536] instead elem.36536 but without success.

Comment: can you paste your original collection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I got your problem right, this code might help you:

```
db.collection.find({"id_field" : 1996}).forEach(function (elem) 
{
   var value = elem['36536'];
   db.collection.update({_id: elem._id},{$set: {name: value}});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your document is like this

```
 {     
    "_id" : 1,
    "elem" : {
        "123" : "barno",
        "456" : "foo@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

you can [$rename](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) the key document.

```
db.d.update({"_id" : 1},{$rename:{'elem.123':'elem.name','elem.456':'elem.email'}})
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "elem" : {
        "name" : "barno",
        "email" : "foo@gmail.com"
    }
}
```